# pandas resample MAX-VALUE with corresponding ANGLE-VALUE

Tags: pandas

I have to resample *wind_velocity* and *wind_angle* from the 2 sec period to 2min and receive the maximum *wind_velocity* (=MAX) with the corresponding *wind_angle* (not MAX). The lines below give me the maximum of both columns.

```
 wind2s = data.ix[:, ['wind_velocity', 'wind_angle']]
 wind2m = wind2s.resample('2m', how='max')
```

the data looks like

```
 In[2]:wind2s.head()
 Out[2]: 
                      wind_velocity  wind_angle
 time                                 
 2014-11-07 10:35:42   0.760          63.72
 2014-11-07 10:35:44   2.278         178.68
 2014-11-07 10:35:46   3.006         179.20
 2014-11-07 10:35:48   2.970         179.16
 2014-11-07 10:35:50   2.882         179.68
```

Any help?

Comment: This answer has a couple strategies - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976669/resampling-in-pandas-while-keeping-value-associations/31977096

Comment: Thank you. This helped. lg, s